# Why is the residue field $Z_{(p)}/(p)Z_{(p)}$ at prime number p isomorphic to Z/pZ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am not a student in math department and I am learning some math by my own. While I was reading this text: https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4215/data/masteragbook.pdf, at page 28, example (2.13). I met this problem.
Defining the residue field k(p) at a prime number p to be $Z_{(p)}/(p)Z_{(p)}$, why is $Z_{(p)}/(p)Z_{(p)}$ isomorphic to $F_{p}$?
Here $Z_{(p)}$ is the local ring at prime ideal (p).
I might make a conceptual mistake, I think k(p) contains the elements that look like $a/b + (p)Z_{(p)}$, where a is an integer while b is not in (p). Then I am considering constructing a map from k(p) to $F_{p}$ as
$$
\phi: a/b + (p)Z_{(p)} \rightarrow a + pZ
$$
But I think this one is not working.

Comment: is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the $p$-adic integers? If so, then thinking of it as the inverse limit of the groups $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ should help you answer your question, at least intuitively.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading, $Z_{p}$ is the local ring at prime ideal (p), which contains the elements look like $ a/b$ where a is an integer and b is not divisible by p.

Comment: No problem, OP. Not certain this is a universal standard, but usually one writes $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ when referring to the localization at $p$, and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ when referring to the completion.

Comment: Thanks for your  suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

This result follows from the fact that localization commutes with quotients. That is, $S^{-1}R/S^{-1}I \cong \overline{S}^{-1} R/I$, where $S$ is the multiplicatively closed set you're introducing as denominators and $\overline{S}$ is its image in the quotient $R/I$. $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$ and the image of the prime $(p)$ in this field is of course zero. So $\overline{S}^{-1} \mathbb{F}_p$ is just the fraction field of $\mathbb{F}_p$, which of course is $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Inspired by your answer, if I want to construct the concrete map, I think I should map 1/b to the b^(-1) in $F_{p}$. Thank you for your kindness.